# Accessing readonly property in testing iOS Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, testing, properties, readonly

I am pretty new to iOS and Swift and currently I'm facing a problem with writing a Unit Test. I have a class (let's suppose it is called A) which has (readonly property from Objective-C) and in my test I want to have object of this class to pass to the method which later does something with it. Oh, I don't have any initializers as well... My question is, how to test such think? Maybe I have to mock such object somehow?

------EDIT-----

Okay. My post wasn't quite precise. Okay, so I know only basics of Swift (unfortunately I don't have time now to learn Objective - C as I was asked to write sth in Swift). I have a class provided by some company in which I have a class (written in Objective-C) like:

```
@interface MainClassX : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString* code;

   @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSArray<XYZ*>* classification;

@end
```

And in my test want to create  an object of this class and init at least 'code' property... but the setter is private so I can't do any 'inheritance trick'...? Is there any option to do it or should I do it another way? The problem is that I want to test a method which takes array of such objects and does sth with them.

Comment: How are instance of `MainClassX` created and the properties initialised?

Comment: Well it's a part of value returned (as a JSON) from server so I suppose it is initialized then.

Comment: So, you either need to fetch the data from a test server as part of your test or mock the object

Comment: Okay. So how to mock such object when the method which I test have such type as an argument? Inheritance? Extension(can I just overwrite such fields)?

Comment: You can subclass the object and provide an initialiser in your subclsss that accesses the underlying ivars to set their values.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty tricky because they wanted those properties to be readonly, why do you want to test them?

Regardless the purpose, you can do these steps:
1. Look into adding methods to that class using Category (in Objective C), or extension(in Swift).
2. Implement that new init method, set the `code` properpty using [Key-Value Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html)

**I have managed to do it real quick in Objective C, it's pretty straight forward to convert to Swift.**

```
@implementation MainClassX(Test)
-(instancetype)initWithCode:(NSString *)code {
    self = [self init];

    if (self) {
        [self setValue:code forKey:@"code"];
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

Test it:

```
MainClassX *test = [[MainClassX alloc] initWithCode:@"TEST"];

NSLog(@"code: %@", test.code); // Should print out "TEST" in the console
```

**Swift:**

```
extension MainClassX {
    convenience init(_ code: String) {
        self.init()
        self.setValue(code, forKey: "code")
    }
}
```

In the unit test:

```
import XCTest
@testable import YourAppModule


class YourAppModuleTests: XCTestCase {

    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        // Put setup code here. This method is called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
    }

    override func tearDown() {
        // Put teardown code here. This method is called after the invocation of each test method in the class.
        super.tearDown()
    }

    func testExample() {
        // This is an example of a functional test case.
        // Use XCTAssert and related functions to verify your tests produce the correct results.
        let cls = MainClassX("TEST")
        XCTAssert(cls.code == "TEST")
    }

    func testPerformanceExample() {
        // This is an example of a performance test case.
        self.measure {
            // Put the code you want to measure the time of here.
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes I know they wanted to make them readonly but now they asked me to write test for my app. I have a method written by me which filters through an Array of such objects and returns reduced amount of them. I wanted to tedt it but I have to pass some tedt data and berify that it filters properly. Ia it a bad idea (maybe I shpuldn't test it at all)? So, comming back to your answer - I should make an extension of this class and make a initializer? :-)

Comment: Yes. That’s the only way to add extension methods into a built in class without touching its source code.

Comment: Well, I'm pretty new to iOS(I come from Java/Kotlin background) and to be honest I haven't had opportunity to catch up with Objective-C so I use 'converter' from Objective-C to Swift. After converting to swift I got  some sort of code, pasted it and it looked fine but I wasn't able to use it in tests. :/ By the way, thanks for support!

Comment: Interesting. Can you give me what you got after conversion?

Comment: I've updated my answer with Swift code. You have to create Objective-C Bridging Header in order to use Swift and Objective C together, See this link for details https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html.

Comment: Sorry for digging out but I just wanted to say that now everything works fine ! Thank you so much! I hope I will get better at great iOS world in some time! :)

Comment: Yeah everything worked fine with 2 classes then I ran into trouble with following error: '"[<ExtendingClass 0x60400043ffc0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key code."' :( my code:

Comment: extension ExtendingClass  {
    convenience init(_ code: String?) {
        self.init()
        self.setValue(code, forKey: "code")
    }
}

Comment: the property looks like: @property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) NSString* code;

Comment: Well, looks like the key path is wrong. You have to look into the class itself. The key path can be something else, not “code”

Comment: In the .m file, look for the @synthesize code and see what it is

Comment: And what is Extending class here?

Comment: Well there are no @synthesize... maybe it's my lack of basic knowledge, the class looks as follows (new post)

Comment: no idea. It's working on my end. And keep in mind, you have to do the extension on the class you want to do it. The key is you have to figure what the key path for the "code" property. Sorry, I can't help you without the source code.

Comment: anyone know what's going on?

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't even get the project compiled and run. Looks like have to pull in the TomTomMap SDK.

Comment: The Swift Initializer with Extension tip with KVC is really helpful for Third-party SDKs  classes with readonly properties (sometimes they provide readonly properties for simple struct data that they provide through callbacks and they don't want you to manipulate them). The main reason why I would use them is to allow Unit Testing functions using this class without having to unwrap the "readonly class" in a custom business logic struct allowing write access.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely looking for dependancy injection. This is a way that you can initialize a class with an optional value that can set values for testing, as you want to do.

The following is a simple example.

Create an optional initialize for your Objective-C class:

```
- (instancetype)initWithOption:(NSString *)option {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.option = option;
    }

    return self;
}
```

You can have it such that when you normally call the class, you call its default init. But for testing, initialize it with this function. Another thing to consider if you may want to have a protected header file (such as `classname_protected.h`) which you only use in your unit tests so that you do not expose this function to your application.

Without seeing more of your test, it is a bit difficult to add on to this, but DI is likely where you need to go for it.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't write any code in that class because it is provided - I posted precise description.